# Step Up power (from 0.02-0.6 DC V input to 5-12 DC V output) I need a suggestion

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I want to design a DC-DC converter to have a power supply that can charge an electronic device.
The issue behind in that the expected input range is 0.04-0.6 V DC. I chose both MT3608 and LTC3108.

The actual issue is my project is using MFCs (Microbial Fuel Cells) , which will be as 12 single chambers, and my job as electrical engineer is stepping up in order to change any battery, such as Lithium-ion battery. Any suggestions to achieve it ?

[image]

---

[image]

My question is.

Q1 / what are the factors (i.e., RLC components) that I need to change in order to achieve my objectives.
Q2 / are there any suggestions to simulate it properly so see the effect of it. I tried LTspice be there were some difficulties.
Q3 / I had an issue behind the factors that are connected to these IC-chips, why these values are connected with them specifically.

Comment: I somehow doubt random step-up converter modules can work from an input voltage this low, but I don't know these. Do you have a datasheet for both the module as well as the IC used in them? If you don't, them you need to find different modules.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the MT3608 can't go that low. It's minimum input is 2v. I think you need a more specialised IC for inputs below 1v.